# Pacote Nuget não aponta para a package instalada

Tags: c#, nuget

Tenho uma aplicação, tal qual faz uso de um pacote `Nuget`.
O pacote em questão é o:

> System.Net.Http

Essa aplicação tem o target framework setado para `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.

Ao checar no projeto para onde a `dll` está sendo referenciada, vejo que o `path` da referencia está apontando para uma pasta do .net framework e não para a pasta "packages" (que é o comum geralmente):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll

A principio esse não é exatamente um problema... Na minha máquina tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Porém tenho um servidor de integração continua, que tem o .net framework 4.7 instalado e mesmo assim acabo obtendo erro ao rodar meus testes.

O erro em questão é este:

> Test method
>   View.Test.DefaultTokenServicoTest.TestaAutorizacaoAPI threw
>   exception:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Agora já não sei se está certo a `dll` apontar para esse caminho ou se falta instalar alguma coisa neste servidor...

Neste servidor consigo buildar,publicar e rodar outros testes normalmente...
Somente os testes que utilizam esse pacote que acaba dando erro.

Alguém saberia dizer o que pode ser?

Arquivo packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="FakeItEasy" version="4.9.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.2.1100" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="2.0.20126.16343" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

E no .csproj tenho o seguinte:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension.5.2.3.0\lib\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension.5.2.3.0\lib\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension.5.2.3.0\lib\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
```

Comment: Só pra descargo de consciência: no servidor, todas as DLL's estão na pasta `bin`, certo?

Comment: Na pasta `bin` tanto na minha máquina quanto no servidor não há essa dll... Não sei pq acaba não sendo copiada. Mas no servidor e na minha máquina eu tenho essa dll na pasta citada lá na pergunta.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta os *.csproj do projeto e do teste, bem como o packages.json. Adicione também a versão da dll nos 2 casos (pode encontrar essa informação nas propriedades da referência, no VS).

Comment: Consegui resolver reinstalando o .net framework. Pelo que entendi essa dll está pegando do GAC, mas ainda não entendi o porque...